# Need to find difference between two characters(Alphabet is cyclic)

Tags: java, string

Given a string, `"azza"`. In this `a-z = 25`, `z-z = 0`, `z-a = 25`. But since alphabet is cyclic, I need `'a'` just after `'z'` i.e., in the above string `z-a = 1`.

For normal string where we dont encounter '`a`' just after '`z`', my code is this

```
class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i;
        int t = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();

        for(i=0;i<t;i++)
        {
            String  s =sc.nextLine();
            char[] string =s.toCharArray();
            for(i=0;i<string.length;i++)
            {
                if((string[i]-string[i+1])==1 || (string[i]-string[i+1])==-1)
                {
                       System.out.println("1");
                }                   
            }               
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: for input `azza`, what will be the output?

Comment: For the string `azzz` what is the correct output? Is your current code producing that output? For the string `azza` what is the correct output? Basically you haven't told us enough to begin to help you. Think carefully about what you want to ask of us and then try and ask it as clearly as you can giving us all the information we would need to be able to answer it. Learning how to ask good questions is a key life skill as well as a requirement of any technical job.

Answer (score 2):

First, reverse subtractions: when you need to compute `z-a` in your scheme, compute `'a'-'z'` and vice versa.

This way you can sometimes arrive at a negative result. When this happens, add 26 to it. This would act as "circling back" to the beginning.

```
char first = 'a';
char last = 'z';
int diff = first - last; // negative 25
if (diff < 0) {
    diff += 26;
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/csCLWN)

Comment: Actually the OP expects a-z = 25 and z-a = 1, what you propose gives the opposite

Comment: @NicolasFilotto That's the first sentence of my answer. When he computes `z-a` in his notation, he should be computing `'a'-'z'` in Java notation. My point is, his notation is inverted with respect to character numbering.

Comment: it is "vice versa" BTW